# "Having a holiday" vs "Spending a holiday"

Tags: word-usage

In my book I found a sentence:

> I was **having** a holiday by **seaside** last summer when I ran into captain Robinson.

I think there are two errors in this sentence. The first one is that there should be **spending** instead of **having**, and the second one is there should be **the seaside**.
Correct me if I am wrong?
I am not sure about if **having** is incorrect here.

Comment: Better off IMHO = "I was having a seaside holiday last summer when I ran into captain Robinson"

Comment: Yeah but be cautious, there, it serves as an adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spending a holiday = having a holiday

Both mean the same that you are enjoying *(not working)* somewhere and that day is a holiday.

[From Jakarta Post](http://www.thejakartapost.com/news/2014/11/20/christmas-comes-early-golf-lovers.html)

> Nusa Dua tourist enclave boasts some of the island’s most exclusive hotels, restaurants and shopping centers. All are set alongside nearly 5 kilometers of well-preserved white sandy beach. ***Spending a holiday*** with the family and golf buddies, therefore, is not an impossible feat to accomplish.

And, if someone is on holiday, they are [having a holiday.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Holiday)

About the *article,* I'll go with you! And [so do many news articles](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22holiday%20by%20the%20seaside%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=nT-RVOzSGJSGuAT-vIK4Dw#q=%22holiday%20by%20the%20seaside%22&tbm=nws)

Also, [this will help you.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42737/is-it-grammatically-correct-to-say-to-swim-at-the-beach/42751#42751)

Answer (score 3):

I'd poke a very tentative alternative explanation for this…

I don't doubt the two terms are pretty much interchangeable, but I feel there is a slightly different flavour to them.

'Having' a holiday is just that, you are on holiday, you are 'having' it, like you'd have an ice cream whilst you're there, or like you'd have a swim.

'Spending' I think is more interested in the 'time spent' & how you spent that time.
"I spent last August in the Dordogne."
"I spent a week on holiday in Spain."

So, referring back - you can 'spend a holiday' but you're really referring to the time you spent away from home.
To torture my analysis still further, you can't spend an ice cream, or a swim, but you can spend time eating ice cream or swimming.

All I really see wrong with the OP's sentence is it ought to be
"I was having a holiday by **the** seaside…" as was mentioned.
I would perhaps posit that
"I was spending my holiday by the seaside" would be a useable alternative, though I'm not sure why swapping 'a' to 'my' really fixes it; perhaps it adds the personal sense of 'time spent' to the sentence.

Comment: Now I am really confused. More information always not good for you. this is the same case with me.

Comment: Sometimes, it's not grammar, it's imagery that is important. "I had a holiday" - fact. "I spent time with friends on holiday" - imagination

Comment: Simple! more info is for more interested people